# In which drawable folder I should put my images?

Tags: android

I have an application that I want to upload to googleplay market. I have a basic question yet. Which drawable folder should I put my images on? I think hdpi,mdpi and ldpi are meant to target cellphones with different screen size and resolutions. But is it okay to put a copy of my images in all three drawable folders or maybe all in hdpi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is: You Should put your images on all of them, but you must have three different image sizes.
If you only have one image size you have to put it on hdpi folder.

Also i strongly recommend you to read this links:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html

Comment: Thank you, So I think I'll just put them all only in drawable/hdpi folder as I only have one size for all my images. putting them in all folders would also double my application size! Sorry I can't vote you up! I don't have enough Rep ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose by the device.

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

**For more info visit to**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

And if are developing the app for only one screen size device then you can create your own folder in ***res/drawable*** and put all your image file there