# I have an image of resolution 1241*2207.In which folder do i put this image into?

Tags: android, image

**Note:This is not a dublicate question as i want to know in terms of actual pixels in width and height which images should be put in which folder.In no question is this asked**

Sorry if this is a beginner question.But I couldn't understand from the official documentation.I have a background image of resolution 1241px width and 2207px height.When i put this image in the drawable(mdpi) folder,the bitmap cannot be loaded because of its size.But when i put this image in hdpi folder the image is loaded.My question is how do i know beforehand which resolution image should be put in which drawable folder?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In which drawable folder I should put my images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063985/in-which-drawable-folder-i-should-put-my-images)

Comment: @RC. I have seen the question.My question is different as i want to know in terms of actual width and height pixels where to put the image in which folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is helpful for you.

```
 xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
    large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
    normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
    small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
    Generalised Dpi values for screens:

    320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).  
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).  
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).  
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

    ldpi
    Vertical = 426 * 120 / 160 = 319.5px
    Horizontal = 320 * 120 / 160 = 240px
    mdpi
    Vertical = 470 * 160 / 160 = 470px
    Horizontal = 320 * 160 / 160 = 320px
    hdpi
    Vertical = 640 * 240 / 160 = 960px
    Horizontal = 480 * 240 / 160 = 720px
    xhdpi
    Vertical = 960 * 320 / 160 = 1920px
    Horizontal = 720 * 320 / 160 = 1440px

    px = dp*dpi/160
```

or

```
    36x36 for low-density (LDPI)

48x48 for medium-density (MDPI)

72x72 for high-density (HDPI)

96x96 for extra high-density (XHDPI)

180x180 for extra extra high-density (XXHDPI)

192x192 for extra extra extra high-density (XXXHDPI)
```